# SNMPTT let hex string sometimes

Tags: encoding, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

Here is a part of the snmptt log file :

```
Tue May 17 22:20:47 2016 .1.3.6.1.4.1.31023.1.1.1.0.1 Normal "Status Events" ssav02 - ef47e072-c8e1-46ef-8c70-645a69bdd489 Backup Job 1 Success 
Tue May 17 23:00:03 2016 .1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.1.2.8.0.5 INFORMATIONAL "Status Events" ssav02 - User advised of event: 42 61 63 6B 75 70 20 45 78 65 63 3A 20 44 E9 62  75 74 20 64 75 20 74 72 61 76 61 69 6C  Job:53 53 41 56 30 32 20 2D 20 53 61 75 76 65 67 61  72 64 65 20 56 65 65 61 6D 2D 43 6F 6D 70 6C E8  74 65  4C 65 20 74 72 61 76 61 69 6C 20 61 20 64 E9 6D  61 72 72 E9 2E 
Wed May 18 01:04:03 2016 .1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.1.2.8.0.7 MINOR "Status Events" ssav02 - User advised of event: Backup Exec: Avertissement de travail
```

There associated to this :

```
EVENT onVmBackupCompleted .1.3.6.1.4.1.31023.1.1.1.0.2 "Status Events" Normal
FORMAT $*
EXEC /usr/local/nagios/libexec/eventhandlers/submit_check_result $2 "Backup Veeam" 0 "$2 : $4 ($5)"
SDESC

This trap is sent on vm backup/replica completed. 
Variables:
  1: backupJobName
  2: vmName
  3: sourceHostName
  4: vmBackupResult
  5: vmBackupComment
EDESC

EVENT jobStarted .1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.1.2.8.0.5 "Status Events" INFORMATIONAL
FORMAT User advised of event: $1 Job:$3 $4
EXEC /usr/local/nagios/libexec/eventhandlers/submit_check_result $r "Sauvegarde ${3}" 0 "User advised of event: $1 Job:$3 $4"
SDESC
The Job has started.
Variables:
  1: messageText
  2: serverName
  3: jobName
  4: additionalText
EDESC

EVENT jobWarning .1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.1.2.8.0.7 "Status Events" MINOR
FORMAT User advised of event: $1
EXEC /usr/local/nagios/libexec/eventhandlers/submit_check_result $r TRAP 1 "User advised of event: $1"
SDESC
The job has a warning.
Variables:
  1: messageText
EDESC
```

As you can see, for some trap, the message is not properly encoded, and the message generated is indescriptible.
So why is my message sometime Hex-string encoded ? How to fix this ?

Comment: Net-SNMP is only capable of printing ASCII charset. So the rest of symbols will be printed as HEX-STRING. Use other SNMP tools that treat UTF-8 encoded data properly.

Comment: Fine; But is there a way, by example to convert all hexadecimal data to string using bash ?

Comment: Bush supports things like `$ echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"`

Comment: Not sure this is a programming question. Did you try ServerFault.com?